# AutoCompleteTextView Items not Clickable when containing ToggleButton

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I ran into a strange problem when dealing with AutoCompleteTextViews.
I've got the following layout for my items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="48dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="8dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Some place I already visited"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/starred"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/starred"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now my Adapter sets the Visiblity of the ToggleButton for some items to Gone and for other to Visible. The ítems where it's gone work as expected you can click them and the text gets put into the AutoCompleteTextView but where the ToggleButton is visible the items don't respond to touch. Altough you can interact with the ToggleButton.

Is there a way to make this work with AutoCompleteTextViews or do I have to use another type of View.

Comment: Simple make the `ToggleButton` not focusable(with `android:focusable="false` or in code `btn.setFocusable(false)`).

Comment: @Luksprog Thank you that worked perfectly, if you would post it as an answer I would happily accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple make the `ToggleButton` from the row not focusable(with `android:focusable="false"` or in code, in the adapter, `btn.setFocusable(false)`).